# Make web service as HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, production

We have a HTTP WebService which is using for our mobile application. Now we are looking to make it as HTTPS (SSL applied).

If we make the web service use HTTPS, then how will this affect existing users of the application?

If it negatively affects existing users, then how can we make my service use HTTPS without affecting the existing users?

Comment: I think @user3056216 probably got the point after 1 or 2 downvotes. Once you work through the language barrier (which was not terribly high), I don't believe the question was so bad it deserved a half a dozen down votes. Is there really a need to downvote him into the stone age? [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by configuring in server. It will not affect any existing users and future users provided you have not hard coded URL in your applications.

Comment: As of now we are using without domain name and URL hard coded in the mobile app client to consume the service.So my sys admin guy trying to setup a domain for this server and apply the ceritificate. And we are thinking that it will be applicable to my service which is already existed in IIS. if this is the case the current URL won't work for the old users .

Comment: Please specify your application server. Probably you need to configure the things in .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the HTTP client library you're using supports redirects, you could issue a redirect from the old `http` URL to the new `https` one.

Comment: wat do u mean by the HTTP client library..and how can we make it to route from http to https in the mobile app for the old users..or you want us to configure this in the server itself ?